# Is it better to update a Highcharts chart or destroy and recreate it?

Tags: highcharts

I am not grappling with a specific problem per se, but I think my question is also more than a mere opinion. When it comes to both best practices and efficiency for Highcharts, is it better to update a chart object, or destroy the chart and create a new one?

I am working on a project with dozens of charts. Some charts required an update of axes, or data format changes to the point where it was determined that building a whole new chart object was the best option. We've started doing this as a standard, even when the charts are to the point and not very complicated. It's got me wondering if the resource expenditure is negligible, or if we're doing ourselves a real disserve.

Here's how our average chart creation works:

1. The page has a variety of menu options
2. When an end user changes a menu option, an API call is made to retrieve new data
3. If new data retrieval is successful, the target chart object is destroyed and a new one created using the data (plus any other chart options we need specific to the menu options, like title, year range, etc...)

If we were updating, then steps 1 and 2 would be the same, but for step 3 instead of destroying the chart object, we just update the series data and chart options.

Is there strong evidence for one method over the other?

Answer (score 2):

As always the best way to find out is to check:

---

Data change in one series with 1000 points: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0ynrwegm/

- recreating time: 37.6337890625 ms
- updating time: 13.60791015625 ms

Data change in ten series with 1000 points and adding new axes: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0ynrwegm/

- recreating time: 214.260009765625 ms
- updating time: 119.7119140625 ms

Update a chart with one series with 1000 points to a chart with nine series, each with 1000 points: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/odks7pyf/

- recreating time: 101.527099609375 ms
- updating time: 114.134033203125 ms

Update a chart with nine series, each with 1000 points to a chart with one series with 1000 points: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ytLrbcf4/

- recreating time: 81.069091796875 ms
- updating time: 16.197998046875 ms

---

So, the answer is: it depends, but in most cases `chart.update()` is much more efficient. You can use the above live examples, swap chart configs to your real ones and check which way is more suitable for you.

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update